# How to close all collapsible divs (accordions) when the modal is dismissed or closed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have developed a modal containing three collapsible divs. When i dismiss the modal and open it again the active collapsible divs are still open. I'd rather want all open collapsibles to be closed except the div with "panel-collapse collapse in" class when the modal gets closed.

PS- I am using Bootstrap 3.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 id="modal-title"> </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div  class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Course Introduction

                            <span class="pull-right"><i id="icon0" class="fa fa-plus open" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            </a>

                            </h4>
                        </div>

                        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                            <p> abc abc abc </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="panel ">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Description
                            <span class="pull-right"><i id="icon" class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>

                        <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Goals
                            <span class="pull-right"><i id="icon" class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>

                        <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>



                </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: you will need to call a js function to close all the open accordions when initiating the action to close the modal

Comment: I have tried but its not working 
`$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) { $('#collapse2').collapse('hide'); });`

Answer (score 1):

You have to toggle collapse to open of the panel, and collapse all collapsible component when hiding modal.

```js
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
 $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
})
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
 $('#collapse1').collapse('show');
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Bootstrap Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<button id="modalButtton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button> 
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 id="modal-title"> </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div  class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Course Introduction

                            <span class="pull-right"><i id="icon0" class="fa fa-plus open" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            </a>

                            </h4>
                        </div>

                        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                            <p> abc abc abc </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="panel ">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Description
                            <span class="pull-right"><i id="icon" class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>

                        <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Goals
                            <span class="pull-right"><i id="icon" class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>

                        <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>



                </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The hidden and shown is not working on my computer. I even tried to copy your code and run it on my computer but no luck. When I inspect your code snippet it is showing hidden and shown event but when I inspect the code locally on my computer the inspector is not showing the hidden and shown event but it is showing the click event on the modal.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to close all accordions when hiding modal and just display the one with panel when opened ? also have you tried running the snippet here?

Comment: please have a look

Comment: The snippet is running fine here on the stackoverflow.com

Comment: There might be some issue, in the way you are adding these snippets. If you are adding JavaScript in a html, make sure to add it before closing `</body>` tag. Here is jsbin link https://jsbin.com/fuqobuk/1

Answer (score 0):

Did you see something in documentation of bootstrap? here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-usage

you could implement some event of modal: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-methods

something like:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $('.collapse').collapse();
})
```

Comment: I have tried but its not working

`$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $('#collapse2').collapse('hide');`
});